# how to add links to user menu, depending on user role?

Tags: users, navigation

I've this problem. I created some user roles on my site. So, when an user becomes actor, I create his actor page, where he can add BIO, demos and his events. 
Now, I want he can access his page from user menu. 
Do I must create some menu_alter in a module? Actor page is a content type, so, I can make request to db.

Comment: Drupal 7 or 8? And the user page is a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create custom module .try this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) . This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and hide it from anonymous users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new menu and make it appear according to permission, role and content type. Put it in the same region as the user menu and style it as if they were one menu. The only drawback I see is that the links are not "mixed" (a link in the menu is between two of the other menu), which should be minor.